# Permutations as solutions of equations over group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $G$ be finite abelian group and $n>2$ integer 
and $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ distinct elements of $G$.

Let $L$ be a system of equations over $G$ in $n$ variables.

Is it possible the solutions of $L$ to be exactly the permutations
of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$?

For $n=2$ it is possible for $G$ the additive subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: Do you want linear equations?

Comment: @verret yes, linear equations.

Comment: In a group, there is just one operation. Could you explain a bit more what your equations look like? (Maybe give the general form for one equation?)

Comment: @verret If the group is additive the general form is $\sum a_i x_i = d$ where a_i are constants and x_i are variables. If the group is multiplicative the general form is $\prod a_i x_i = d$.

Comment: Are the constants also coming from the group?  If yes, what does $a_ix_i$ denote in the additive case? And couldn't you just collect all constants in the multiplicative case? $\prod a_ix_i=a' \prod x_i$, where $a'=\prod a_i$.

Comment: @verret Thanks for the feedback. The additive constants are integers, not elements of the group. The multiplicative case is wrong, looks like I need exponents...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Aren't solution sets of such systems of equations simply cosets of subgroups of $G^n$, by the standard linear algebra proof? (The solution set of the corresponding homogeneous system is a subgroup, and so on...)